# word-break: break-word doesn't work in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a text in flexbox item `.learn--text` which needs to be vertically centered, but `word-break: break-word` rule doesn't work.

This is the current state

[image]

and desired state

[image]

```css
.learn {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}

.learn--icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.learn--text {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 6px;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn"><div class="learn--icon">icon</div><span class="learn--text"><a href="#">Learn more</a> about content management →
</span></div>
```

Comment: Try `overflow-wrap: break-word` with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: if its to keep <a> in one column and the text wrapping aside  in the next column, remove flex-wrap from learn--text https://jsfiddle.net/pmtzcv2e/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thanks, but in your case the text also doesn't break correctly. I don't want to divide `Learn more about content management` into two separate columns.

Comment: @Kameron I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/L9m7cq4v/) it out, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erase all the flex settings from `learn--text` - they "divide" its content into two parts, the link and the following text, treating them as flex items and therefore units. If you erase that, the result is as follows:

```css
.learn {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}

.learn--icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.learn--text {
    padding: 0 6px;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn"><div class="learn--icon">icon</div><span class="learn--text"><a href="#">Learn more</a> about content management →
</span></div>
```

Comment: but then the `.learn--text` is not vertically centered

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I just edited and changed `align-items` to `center;` for the `.learn` container – is it that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This, is the answer:

```css
.learn {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}

.learn--icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.learn--text {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 6px;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn"><div class="learn--icon">icon</div><span class="learn--text"><a href="#">Learn more</a> about content management →
</span></div>
```